# How to make a simple search function in linq and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to simply search a database for a certain string, how can i accomplish this using linq and EF (if using these tools for it are not practical I am open to any suggestions).  I just want to take a string and search my usernames, the search should be able to handle things only parts of the username (using some sort of 'contains' function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics of what you are asking is..

```
var found = MyContext.Users.Where(user => user.UserName.Contains(searchString));
```

You would need to substitute actual entity names/values for the example code posted.